# Duplicate rows when 2 tables are joined

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a query which reads the description of the code.
Both the queries run individually they return one row but combined it gives one more duplicate row.Below are the queries

```
SELECT source, description = IsNull(Max(RTRIM(LTRIM(description))), 'UNKNOWN') 
  FROM SOURCES where source = RTRIM(LTRIM('SCDGIFT12')) 
 GROUP BY source

SELECT UPPER(SOURCECODE) as SOURCECODE,ISNULL(COUNT(ORDER_ID),0) AS ORDID 
  FROM SRC_CODE
 WHERE  CODE = 'SCDGIFT12' AND ORDER_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/01/2013')     
   AND  CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/26/2014') 
 GROUP BY sourcecode

SELECT SOURCECODE,ORDID,DESCRIPTION 
  FROM ( SELECT UPPER(SOURCECODE) as SOURCECODE, ISNULL(COUNT(ORDER_ID),0) AS ORDID )     
           FROM SRC_CODE  
          WHERE SOURCECODE = 'SCDGIFT12' and ORDER_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/01/2013') AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'01/26/2014')AND (UPPER(SOURCECODE) IS NOT NULL)  
          GROUP BY  UPPER(SOURCECODE)) AS T LEFT JOIN ( 
                SELECT source, description =  IsNull(Max(RTRIM(LTRIM(description))), 'UNKNOWN') from SOURCES group by source) as B ON  RTRIM(LTRIM(T.SOURCECODE)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(B.SOURCE))  
  ORDER BY sourcecode
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know where to start to answer this one.

- Your questions is incorrect, you are not joining two tables. You are joining two different results sets.
- In first 2 statements you only have two columns, but in last statement you have 3 columns.
- Your code is invalid as it is, there are several syntax errors that need to be corrected before it could even compile. Your parenthesis are in wrong places.
- I'm not even sure what is that you are joining.
- When joining and counting, you should put apples with apples and oranges with oranges, not try to count them separate and after put them together and expect both to be the same.

Here is your code reformatted and parenthesis moved to correct place "i hope"

```
SELECT SOURCECODE
   ,ORDID
   ,DESCRIPTION
FROM ( SELECT UPPER(SOURCECODE) AS SOURCECODE
           ,ISNULL(COUNT(ORDER_ID), 0) AS ORDID
        FROM SRC_CODE
        WHERE SOURCECODE = 'SCDGIFT12'
            AND ORDER_DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '10/01/2013')
                           AND     CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/26/2014')
            AND ( UPPER(SOURCECODE) IS NOT NULL )
        GROUP BY UPPER(SOURCECODE) ) AS T
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT source
                   ,description = ISNULL(MAX(RTRIM(LTRIM(description))), 'UNKNOWN')
                FROM SOURCES
                GROUP BY source ) AS B
    ON RTRIM(LTRIM(T.SOURCECODE)) = RTRIM(LTRIM(B.SOURCE))
ORDER BY sourcecode
```

I'm not sure what you even wanted to do with this, but if all you want is to get rid of duplicate you can put `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicate rows, but that does not solve your underlying problem. You need to figure out what is that you are trying to count and figure out better way to put it together instead of joining sub-query.